# What is the contribution of dependent sources while calculating the Thevenin’s Voltage?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, circuit-theory

I was solving a problem and while calculating the Thevenin’s voltage the dependent voltage source contribution was not taken into account.Why?What important concept am I missing?
[image]

Comment: Are you saying that you *did* take it into account and the grader said you shouldn't have, or the other way around?  It should be taken into account for both the equivalent voltage and the equivalent resistance calculations, and the calculations given appear to be correct.

Comment: As per the solution they have not taken that in account.How does that work?

Comment: If "they" did the printed solution, it's in the first line of the math, right under the "ly" in "apply", \$+ 4V_o\$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependent source is used in the solution given:

[image]

The term I circled is the contribution of the dependent source to the KVL equation.